# Wijmo Grid. Get rownumber for row with matching Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, wijmo

I have a Wijmo Grid where the first column is Id.

```
$("#logGrid").wijgrid({
    loaded: loadedHandler,
    columns: [
        { headerText: "Id", dataType: "string", dataKey: "Id", visible: false },
        { headerText: "Foo", dataType: "datetime", dataKey: "Foo", },
        { headerText: "Bar", dataType: "string", dataKey: "Bar" }
    ],
    data: datasource
});
```

I want to get the row number, for the row with the same Id as the parameter (defaultSelectedLogId).

I have tryed with:

```
var getRowNumber = function (defaultSelectedLogId) {
    var rowNumbertest = $("#logGrid").closest('tr').prevAll().length;
    var rowNumbertest2 = $("#logGrid tr").prevAll().length; // Result: 7 (total row numbers)

    var rowNumber = $("#logGrid tr").cell("id=[" + defaultSelectedLogId + "]").prevAll().length;
    var rowNumber2 = $("#logGrid tr id=[" + defaultSelectedLogId + "]").cell.column().dataKey.prevAll().length;
    var rowNumber3 = $("#logGrid tr").cell.column().dataKey.prevAll().length;

    return rowNumber;
}
```

I should be simple. 1) Iterate the rows. 2) Find the row with Id equals to the giving parameter. 3) return the row number.

EDIT:
Inspecting the table with firebug, it have the structure like this:

```
<tbody class="ui-widget-content wijmo-wijgrid-data">
    <tr class="wijmo-wijgrid-row ui-widget-content wijmo-wijgrid-datarow" role="row">
        <div class="wijmo-wijgrid-innercell">56259</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return the zero based index of the row

```
var rowNumber = $('div:contains(' + defaultSelectedLogId + ')').closest('tr').index();
```

EDIT: It works now, but must use single quote instead of double quote.

Comment: It dosn't work, but you might be close.
What about LogGrid (the table id). Don't I need that?
Remember defaultSelectedLogId is the Id that would match one of the rows in the grid.

Comment: You shouldn't need the table ID. Can you check `$('#' + defaultSelectedLogId).length;` to ensure you are actually selecting an element.

Comment: ReferenceError: defaultSelectedLogId is not defined.

Comment: defaultSelectedLogId is just the a int parameter. In my test i use 56260, witch match the 3rd row. I think I only are missing something like `id=[" + defaultSelectedLogId + "]"` to get the right row.

Comment: Try hardcoding `var rowNumber = $('#' + '56260').closest('tr').index();` - it should work and return 3

Comment: Please look at my edit. You can see the structure of the table and the id im trying to get and compare with `defaultSelectedLogId`

Comment: I misunderstood your meaning of id (assumed you had an element with attribute id="###"). I'll update my answer.

Comment: You got it now, well done. Note I fixed a little bug, where you used double quotes instead of single, but you did the heavy lifting for sure :)